# jQuery .ready() calling a javascript object, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, mobile

I'm trying to call a JS object's method on pageload. Here's my code:

```
var mobileScreen = {
  scWidth : $(window).width(),

  resizeElems : function(W) {
    console.log("About to resize!");
  }
}

$(document).ready( mobileScreen.resizeElems($(window).width()) );
```

My jQuery .ready() method isn't recognizing mobileScreen.resizeElems() as a function (my editor is not doing any syntax highlighting on it.

My console comes back empty, my code never gets inside resizeElems().

I've tried adjusting my .ready() function like so:

```
$(document).ready( function() { mobileScreen.resizeElems($(window).width()) } );
```

But I get the same result. Am I missing something about calling my object's resizeElems method?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your second example probably works as you expect; what is the “same result”? Editor highlighting? You could try adding a semicolon after the statement in the function literal.

Comment: I don't get anything in the console. It never gets inside resizeElems.

Comment: the first one does not work because you are trying to set the result of the function, and not the function itself to be called

Comment: I thought it might be something like that as well, but the second one failed as well. Likely for different reasons, but the result is the same.

Comment: The second one does not fail, it works.

Comment: Maybe you aren't loading jquery at all? Can you show what scripts you are loading?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example doesn't work because [$.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) takes a function. `mobileScreen.resizeElems($(window).width())` does not return a function so it would not work.

Your second example should work just fine, here it is on a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/T3VtH/

Make sure you have a script tag in your HTML to load the jQuery library and that it appears in the HTML before your code.

Comment: And it works. Check the console. If your console log isn't showing anything, try restarting your browser, that happens to me on rare occasions.